# CSS Wrapping rows of <span>s issues

Tags: html, css

I have this data:

```html
<div id="results">
  <span id="row">
    <span id="left">left column</span>
  <span id="middle">middle text</span>
  <span id="right">right stuff</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to emulate this:

[image]

Here is my CSS Code:

```css
#results {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#row {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#middle {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#right {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
  <span id="row">
        <span id="left">left column</span>
  <span id="middle">middle text</span>
  <span id="right">right stuff</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The problem is, that it turns out like this!

[image]

It looks fine except to the right of the right span block, that green chunk there is supposed to be the `#row` wrapper. Why isn't it wrapping like it should?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to your `#row` **span** Because **span** is an `inline element` which didn't take `width` & `height` by default.

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/2xufx/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow: auto` to the `#results` and to the `#row` definition, and you also need to add `display: block` to `#row` (or just make it a block element for e.g. a `<div/>`) to make it work.

CSS:

```
#results    { width: 700px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto; }
#row        { display: block; width: 85%; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid green; overflow: auto;  }
#left       { float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue; }
#middle     { float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue; }
#right      { float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue; }​
```

See the working [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gvatg/).

But keep in mind that width (200px) + the border (2px) + margin (10px) = 212px, multiplying it by 3 = 636px, and 85% of 700px is 595px that's why it does not fit.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner elements are using `float` you have to 'reset'. E.g. by using `overflow: hidden;` on the parent.

Also you are trying to set a width on an `inline` element (the `span`), which cannot be done. Change it to either `block` or `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help you

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
    #results    {width: 700px; margin: 0px auto; border: 1px solid black; min-height: 50px;}
    #row        {width: 92%; margin: 0px auto; border: 2px solid green; min-height: 30px;}
    #left       {float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue;}
    #middle     {float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue;}
    #right      {float: left; width: 200px; margin:5px 5px 5px 5px; border: 1px solid blue;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results">
<div id="row">
<span id="left">left column</span>
<span id="middle">middle text</span>
<span id="right">right stuff</span>
</div>
<div id="row">
<span id="left">left column</span>
<span id="middle">middle text</span>
<span id="right">right stuff</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Out put which i get it

[image]